# Filter model with HasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

Let's say I have two models: `Park` and `Items`. Each `Park` can have a number of `Items`, through a `HasMany` relationship.

In `Items` table there's a `park_id` field and a `type` flag: an `Item` can be a fountain, or a basketball court, or whatever.

What I need to do is to filter the parks to obtain only those who has ALL of the item types passed in an array. This is what I have:

```
$parks = Park::whereHas('items', function($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('type', json_decode($request->type_list));
        })->get();
```

But it's not working properly. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot, and happy new year to all!

Edit: I've found a working though really ugly solution:

```
$types_array = json_decode($request->type_list, true);

$results = [];

// A collection of parks for each item type
foreach($types_array as $type) {
    $results[] = Park::whereHas('items', function($q) use ($type) {
        $q->where('type', $type);
    })->get();
}

// Intersect all collections
$parks = $results[0];
array_shift($results);

foreach ($results as $collection) {
    $parks = $collection->intersect($parks);
}

return $parks;
```

Comment: Few question: **1)** What version of Laravel are you using? **2)** What is the output of `dd( json_decode($request->type_list));`? **3)** Please can you  explain how *it's not working properly*?

Comment: Hi Ross, sorry for the lack of info.
1) 5.4
2) ["ag","zd"] (this is working fine)
3) I'm not getting a list of parks with ALL of the item types, but a list of parks with SOME of the item types. I need a collection of parks satisfying all the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a foreach in whereHas method. It should be something like this:

```
$array = json_decode($request->type_list, true)
$parks = Park::whereHas('items', function($q) use ($array) {
             foreach ($array as $key => $type) {
                 $q->where('type', $type);
             }
         })->get();
```

Comment: Hi Laerte. Thanks for your answer, but I'm getting the same results. I obtain a collection of parks with SOME of the items, but I need the parks with ALL of the items. I guess I'm missing some kind of  'join' statement, but I have no idea on how to implement it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you need. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Please, check if the edited answer solves the problem.

Comment: Mmm, I think we're at the same point. First, I get an error with 'andWhere' statement, since it doesn't exist, and if I replace it with 'where' or 'orWhere' I get similar results. I'm trying a different approach getting different collections for each item type and then intersecting them.

Comment: I've copied this code from an `orWhere` code I have, I'm sorry. But, this should work, since it is creating several `AND` statements in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think using where clause to match all item's type for the same row will result nothing, it's like doing `where id = 1 and id = 2`  and this is impossible because id can take only one value, what you should do is to use `whereIn` to get all items that match at least one type and then use `groupBy` to group result by `park_id`, then in the having clause you can check if the group count equal the `type_list` count:

```
$types = json_decode($request->type_list, true);

$parks = Park::whereHas('items', function($q) use ($types) {

    $q->select('park_id', DB::raw('COUNT(park_id)'))
      ->whereIn('type', $types)
      ->groupBy('park_id')
      ->havingRaw('COUNT(park_id) = ?', [ count($types) ]);

})->get();
```

Comment: Hi YouneL, I get the point and you're right, but I get this error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '****.items.type' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `parks` where exists (select `type`, COUNT(park_id) from `items` where `parks`.`id` = `items`.`park_id` and `type` in (ai) group by `park_id` having COUNT(park_id) = 1))

Comment: Sorry, the select method should be `$q->select('park_id', DB::raw('COUNT(park_id)'))`, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `whereHas()` constraint to one query:

```php
$types_array = json_decode($request->type_list, true);
$query = Park::query();
foreach($types_array as $type) {
    $query->whereHas('items', function($q) use($type) {
        $q->where('type', $type);
    });
}
$parks = $query->get();
```